# Install mod_wsgi on Ubuntu with Python 3.6, Apache 2.4, and Django 1.11

Tags: apache-http-server, python, django, python3, mod-wsgi

**How do I get mod_wsgi for Apache2 that was compiled for Python 3.6.1?**

(or any future Python version)

I am using a Python 3.6.1 virtual environment with Django 1.11 and Everything is working according to the Apache error log except that mod_wsgi for Apache 2.4 was compiled for Python/3.5.1+ and is using Python/3.5.2 so my Python 3.6.1 code is failing because I'm using new features not available in 3.5.2

All of the other configurations and installs involved in setting my system up seem to be fine (Running in daemon mode) though mod_wsgi doesn't seem to be using my Python 3.6.1 virtual environment (though it is trying to use it for Django according to the error log)...

**I used:** `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` to install mod_wsgi for Apache 2.4

**I used:** `./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6` and `make` with `make install` to install mod_wsgi for Python 3.6

*I must be doing something wrong - please correct me!*

Here is my Apache Error Log (cleaned a bit) - and yes I know it fails on the f"" string line (python 3.6 feature not in 3.5)

```
[wsgi:warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[wsgi:warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[wsgi:warn] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[wsgi:warn] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=12963): Target WSGI script '/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/tir/tir/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=12963): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/tir/tir/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/tir/tir/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[wsgi:error]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
[wsgi:error]     app_config.ready()
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
[wsgi:error]     self.module.autodiscover()
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
[wsgi:error]     autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
[wsgi:error]     import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
[wsgi:error]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[wsgi:error]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
[wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
[wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/tir/company/admin.py", line 13, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     from .forms import AdminInteractionForm
[wsgi:error]   File "/home/jamin/www/dev.tir.com/tir/company/forms.py", line 87
[wsgi:error]     resp = f"Hi {user.first_name}, you'll need to login to send any more suggestions. \\
[wsgi:error]                              \\n\\nFirst Time? Check your email/spam for login instructions from us."
[wsgi:error]                                                                                        
[wsgi:error]                                                                                                   ^
[wsgi:error] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

*also tir.com is shorthand for my actual site - i do not have anything to do with that domain

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the `apt` version, install `mod_wsgi` with `pip` in the environment that you will use and then link the installed `mod_wsgi` to Apache. Here is the answer that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682386/4454597